# How can I run a script on resolution change?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, video

I want to run a script when my current resolution changes, right now I have a sleep loop polling `xrandr`, but I would like to have my script run on some kind of resolution-change event instead. Is it possible?

Comment: this script uses xlib https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907491/how-to-use-xlib-to-listen-for-screen-resolution-changes-on-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I couldn't find a suitable solution to my problem and so I wrote my own program to solve it. xeventbind will fire up your script when the resolution changes.

[Here's a link to github repository](https://github.com/ritave/xeventbind)